# Bash: how to pass arguments with special characters like \t

Tags: bash, shell, arguments

I got a question of how to pass arguments with special characters like `\t`, in Bash.

I know the following to preserve quotes:

```
function my_grep {
    cmd="grep '$@'"
    eval $cmd;
}
```

so that I can do `my_grep "hello world"`.

But it seems that I can't preserve \t in this way, e.g.

```
my_grep "hello\tworld"
```

Any ideas on how to make this work?

Comment: is this function to be used in your `.bashrc`? Also, how do you intend to specify a file or file-pattern to search?

Comment: If you want to preserve quotes, you need to escape quotes. You're just replacing quotes and using `eval` with user input, which is a [big security issue](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048).

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: correct, something like that file. The search pattern may look like "hello\tworld", \t will be typed by ctrl+v TAB in terminal.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The solution is simple: don't store your command in a variable! See [BashFAQ #50: I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050). Also, don't use `eval`; it causes all sorts of weird problems. If you skip those (and use `"$@"` properly), the problem vanishes:

```
my_grep() {
    grep "$@"
}
```

Note that if you call this with `my_grep "hello\tworld"`, it doesn't actually pass in a tab character, it passes a backslash followed by the letter "t" -- which some implementations of `grep` interpret as matching a tab. If your version of `grep` doesn't do that, you can pass an actual tab with `my_grep $'hello\tworld'`.

Comment: `don't store your command in a variable!` is not always correct. However +1.

Comment: @konsolebox: how about "don't store your command in a variable without a good reason!"? In this case, the question didn't indicate any reason at all, so I left the qualification off...

Comment: @GordonDavisson That certainly is considerable.

Answer (score -4):

You can use `-F` option in `grep` for literal string. Test script:

```
 #!/bin/bash

 function my_grep {
    cmd="grep -F '$@' hello.txt"
    eval $cmd
 }

 my_grep "hello world\t"
```

For the input file:

```
 $ cat hello.txt 
 hello world\t
 hello world
```

The output is:

```
 $ sh grep_test.sh 
 hello world\t
```

Also, I would change the `function` lines with (personally, I'd rather avoid `eval`):

```
 result=`grep -F "${@}" hello.txt`
 echo $result
```

Hope this helps.